# Given a compact topological space, then every continuous function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $X$ is compact show that $C(X)=CB(X)$ where $C(X)$ is the space of all cts functions defined on $X$ , and $CB$ means continuous and bounded functions.

My Idea: Approach with contradiction, assume $f$ is continuous on $X$ but unbounded in $Y$ equipped with sup norm $\|f\|=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in X\}$(I'm not sure If I should use sup norm, but since the question didn't specify any way of saying a function is bounded, I'll use sup norm.) and then try to show the sets $D_n=\{x\in X :\|f\|<n\}$ is open for all integer $n>0$. Then use the fact that $X$ is compact to reach a contradiction. But I found myself having a hard time arguing $D_n$ is open, I was trying to show it is open in the following ways, either show $D_n$ is a neighborhood of every point in it, or the complement is closed. But not reaching any where. Any suggestions or hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Continuous maps send compact set to compact set, and any compact subset of $\mathbb R$ is bounded.

Comment: Allthough it does not affect the answer very much, you should include the image space in your question. Typically, when you write $C(X)$ it is either of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ but your approach suggests that you are working in general normed spaces.

Comment: An assumption that should be included to define boundedness is the the codomain is 1) metrizable and 2) has a kind of norm to define |f(x)|.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach can be made to reflect the (far simpler) proof given by ‘just a user’. But as $\|f\|$ is a *constant* (if $f$ is bounded, that is - if $f$ is not bounded, then every $D_n$ is empty as $\|f\|=\infty$), it will not work. Though your definition of $D_n$ makes them either empty of the whole of $X$, both of which are open.

It is much better to take $D_n:=\{x:|f(x)|<n\}$. This is open since the function $|f|$ is continuous. Their union covers $X$. Note that $D_m\subseteq D_n$ if $n\ge m$. By compactness, there is a finite subcover - by the ascending property I mention, that amounts to the existence of $N\in\Bbb N$, that $X=D_N$.

That automatically proves $f$ is bounded. No contradiction needed: $|f(x)|<N$ for all $x$, necessarily.

My proof here really is ‘essentially the same’ as the observation that continuous functions map compact subspaces to compact subspaces, and that a compact subspace of $\Bbb R$ is bounded. I give this proof only to show you how to rescue your approach. The latter proof has an advantage: not only is it more natural, but it also reveals that $f$ will actually *attain* its bound. This is just the extreme value theorem! The idea of your proof has the advantage that it shows any *countably* compact $X$ will do, and that full compactness is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few assumptions that are hinted at in the problem that are not explicitly said.

Let $(A,\mathcal{T})$ be a compact topological space. Let $f:A\to B$ be a continuous function.

First to speak about boundedness, we need a metric on $B$ i.e. $(B,d)$ is a metrizable space with $d$ the metric on $B$

Now since $f$ is continuous, and $A$ is compact then $f(B)$ is compact.
Additionally, and since $f(B)$ is metrizable and compact, then $f(B)$ is bounded. We can say that $f$ is bounded in the metric sense. i.e. There exists $M\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that for every $x\in A$, for every $y\in A$
$$d(f(x),f(y))\le M$$

On the other hand, the existence of $\sup$, $\vert\vert . \vert\vert$, and $\vert.\vert$ need more assumptions since it is possible that $B\not\subseteq \mathbb{R}$